# php login form and submit button

Tags: php, html, css

I have php login script that I have modified with htm tables and css.   I would like to replace the submitt button with an image.  However when on line 64

**From**

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
```

**To**

```
<input type="image" name="Submit" value="Login" src="../img/as.jpg">
```

The page loads correctly but the link submitt does not work.

Any ideas appreciated.  I have include sample code in the dropbox link below.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3333282/button_image_problem.zip

Thanks,  I would like to ackowledge that this code was originally written by some one whose name is on my home machine.  Sorry to the writer.

Henry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input type can't be image. That is not valid html. If you want to use an image as the submit-button, you will have to use css to do that.

`<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" class="submitwithimage">`

Apply a class like such ^ and read this article for more explanation:
http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2009/04/24/how-to-style-a-submit-button-in-css/

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit_X']) || isset($_POST['Submit_Y'])){}
```

in place of

```
if ($_POST['Submit']=='Login'){}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" style="background-image:url('IMAGE_URL');" name="Submit" value="Login">
```

There's another way also

```
<script>
function submitform() {
document.getElementById("formID").submit();
}
</script>
<img src="SOME_URL" onclick="submitform();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code ...

when you take image button then in post you will have this..

```
Array
(
    [email] => 
    [pwd] => 
    [Submit_x] => 0
    [Submit_y] => 0
)
```

so you need to make if condition accordingly